# Interpolating complex react native animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a rather complex example I wanted to try and get working, perhaps someone better at maths than me has a better approach. Code so far: https://gist.github.com/kyle-ssg/697570a7d5edc0e14cc6967b2e40b7ba.

I have a container component that scales from 1 to 4 and a child component I wish to keep in the exact same position throughout (i.e. appear not to also scale) so that I can mask it using overflow:hidden.

My approach was to essentially negate the scale and translate the x and y appropriately as the scale of the parent increases. I thought that my approach was working as I could adjust the animated value from 0 to 1 along with any widths/heights and positions and the start and finish was exactly what I expected

https://ibb.co/TTCkN8M (start) https://ibb.co/KwKfW4F (finish)

However, when animating the value between 0 and 1 it seems to start and end correctly but not animate appropriately inbetween (i.e. the red square staying in place). http://g.recordit.co/HPEkMyvVOf.gif

Answer (score 0):

In the end I didn't need this, using react-native-masked-view achieved what I wanted.